# css - Divs not coming in a proper way

Tags: html, css

I have a number of divs on my page but of two types. The first type is "main item" and the second is "sub item". The problem is that the sub items are overlapping the main items.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CcPyG/

For more clearance here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
    Item 1
    <div class="sub-item">  
        Sub Item 1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    Item 2
    <div class="sub-item">  
        Sub Item 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    Item 3
    <div class="sub-item">  
        Sub Item 3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    Item 4
    <div class="sub-item">  
        Sub Item 4
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    Item 5
    <div class="sub-item">  
         Sub Item 5
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
    font-family: Menu;
    color: White;
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 35px;
    color:black;
}
.sub-item {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `height: 35px;`

Comment: you have a static height of your .item's.  this makes them only bound to 35px.  try changing it to auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `item` holds the `sub-item`. The problem is that `item` has a fixed height of 35px. `sub-item` has a top-margin of 40px. This means that the distance from the top of item to the top of `sub-item` is 40 px -- which is larger than the whole size of `item` itself!

To solve, remove the `height: 35px` from `.item` in your CSS. See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CcPyG/1/).

Answer (score 2):

You have a fixed `height` of `35px` for the parent `.item`. The reason they're overlapping is because ... well, the next div starts where the current one ends, and since you gave a margin of `40px` to the child, it appears in the next div.

If you want to show everything without overlaps, set the height to `auto`? I guess I'd need to know **why** you chose the `height:35px` before I can form a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Please delete the height in the `.item`:

```
.item {
    font-family: Menu;
    color: White;
    width: 250px;
    **/*height: 35px;*/**
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 35px;
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Adrift.

Answer (score 1):

You have a height set on the the .item div that is smaller than the top margin on the .sub-item.  Remove the height and it will flow properly.  What are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.item {
    color: black;
    font-family: Menu;
    /*height: 35px;*/
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 250px;
}
```